# django: Changing auto_id of ModelForm based form class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Every time I create an instance of the `TestForm` specified below, I have to overwrite the standard id format with `auto_id=True`. How can this be done once only in the form class instead? Any hints are very welcome.

views.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Test

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test

def test(request):
    form = TestForm(auto_id=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the argument in constructor:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(auto_id=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.auto_id = True
    class Meta:
        model = Test
```